# Spring Cloud Config Client Actuator Refresh

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a Client which listens to config server. Config Server is pointing to github. Things work fine with localhost. However when i deploy the application to Kubernetes the Client endpoint to refresh the properties doesn't work properly.

Endpoint (Post) : http://config-client.sbx.com/actuator/refresh

This returns an empty response on Postman "[]" and Response code is 200 OK. I am able to see that the Config server is up and running on K8s.

Any suggestion on what could be wrong?

P.S. I have enabled DEBUG logs but do not see much information there.

Comment: Can the kubernetes node hit GitHub?

Comment: Yes i am able to fetch the properties from Github on the config server. Somehow not able to access it from the client which is running on a different pod. 

Both the pods however are running on 8080 and i have added the property in bootstrap.yml on Client to have the actuator listening w/o SSL.

Comment: Did you try requesting on http://config-client.sbx.com/refresh

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if the application link has got the hostname and the application name when doing the refresh. Because while doing a refresh in the localhost, it will just be springboot application locally, so there wont be any need for an additional path of application-name. Wherehas when you deploy to a server normally we have to give the path name of the application in addition to the hostname. In tomcat, the URL I use is as below,

```
http://<hostname>/**<application-name>**/actuator/refresh/
```

Normally when you hit this URL via postman, it will give you a 200 response with an empty body of []. And then, you should be able to see the below lines in the log files of the client application. [ Also I had the attribute **@RefreshScope** attribute at the main method of the application just below the @SpringBootApplication attribute to refresh the attributes of the application.]

```
INFO   o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment:249 - Fetching config from server at : http://<hostname>/<Config-server-application-name>/
INFO   o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.log:168 - Located environment: name=config-client, profiles=[development], label=null, version=ab36989c85922f1c9cf7803fac4, state=null
INFO   o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize:112 - Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-https://<gitlaburl>/<companyname>/config-server.git/config-client-development.yml'}]
INFO   o.s.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupProfileInfo:655 - The following profiles are active: development
INFO   o.s.boot.SpringApplication.logStarted:61 - Started application in 1.557 seconds (JVM running for 70689.032)
```

For Kubernetes,

Try using

> kubectl apply

(instead of kubectl create configmap.)

To deploy the config map, just run the following command on Kubernetes:

```
kubectl apply -f config-map.yml
```

Make sure the name of the config map matches the name of the spring boot application .Also see the below link ,

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/255

Also there is a spring cloud kuberenetes which you can explore as below,

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#why-do-you-need-spring-cloud-kubernetes